# Headless Chrome gives command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128) error, sometimes

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-20.04, google-chrome-headless

I use Google Chrome to produce PDFs of webpages. I have noticed that once in a while, Chrome errors out. I started playing with it and from the command line, even when I execute Chrome with the bare minimum of flags, it errors out on occasion. This is the command I run:

```
google-chrome --headless --no-sandbox
```

And this is the error I get. But only *sometimes*. Most of the time, only the two warnings are triggered, and Chrome loads as expected.

```
[0930/042541.982039:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(247)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0930/042542.096418:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(380)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0930/042542.120932:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(128)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
```

I've been trying to make sense out of the error, but the best I have come up with is that it's related to some sort of memory issue. What's confusing to me is that most of the time, it works fine.

I've gone through the [list of flags](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches) and tried playing with turning off most of the features I don't need, but even so, the error appears, *sometimes*. Has anyone experienced a similar issue?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.05 LTS with Google Chrome 106.0.5249.61.

Answer (score 0):

Disables GPU hardware acceleration. If software renderer is not in place, then the GPU process won't launch. ↪
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-gpu

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, sadly, that wasn't it unfortunately.  (I wasn't the one that downvoted btw, all suggestions are welcome.)

Comment: I found that --disable-gpu should prevent the ERROR of "failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer."